# Map method to get Map values() fields issue

Tags: map, opportunitycontactrole

I have a Map, key is opportunityId and value is OpportunityContactRole. In value of map i have Put OpportunityId, contactId , contact.Name , Id etc. I need to get Contact.Name from values of map. For that i have done something but not working Please help , my Code is below:

```
 Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole> mapOppId_ConId = new Map<Id , OpportunityContactRole>(); 
for(OpportunityContactRole OppConrole :  [SELECT OpportunityId, Contact.Name, ContactId, Contact.Email FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE isPrimary=true AND Contact.Preferred_Language__c='EN' AND OpportunityId IN : setOppId]){    
    mapOppId_ConId.put(OppConrole.OpportunityId , OppConrole ); 
}

for(Id oppId : mapOppId_ConId.keyset()){
    singleMail.setTargetObjectId(mapOppId_ConId.get(oppId).ContactId); 
    String message   = '\n Dear :'+ mapOppId_ConId.get(oppId).Contact.Name; // added .get here --martin
}
```

In string message I am not getting contact name. How can I acheive this?

Comment: Are you sure it has one?

Comment: It appears to me as though you're doing it correctly. You may want to sort your data and/or use a debug statement before putting the data into your map to make certain `isEmpty(Contact.Name) == false`.

Comment: Is it possible that the API user performing the query doesn't have sufficient access to the Contact in question. See  [OpportunityContactRole](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm).ContactId documentation description.